# Many images on one page (html, generated with php), often a part of images not loading

Tags: php, html, image, gd, loading

I have a long html page with many images (to print all property images), which is generated by php. A part of images not loading often, I just see the titles. When I look at source code - all paths are right!

See the screenshot: http://imm.io/wtuG

If I reboot the page (ctrl + R and Ctrl + F5) - the same problem is on the page.
I tried to use `ini_set("max_execution_time", "5000")` - didn't help.

All images which are not in loop are displayed, just images in the `foreach()` loop are not loaded always.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I used the jQuery.resize() plugin. When I disabled this plugin - all images are loading well! So, the problem is in resize() plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use **header('Cache-Control: no-cache');** and **flush();**?